# Can't start an instance due to "(sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file" error

Tags: juju, openstack

I've just installed OpenStack by Autopilot.

i can't start an instance:

```
nova start admin_instance_1

Instance e7030ddb-df04-4d7e-b3ca-ac18b744d434 is not ready (HTTP 409) (Request-ID: req-6bfa35ac-21f5-4c65-8b3d-fa40ee028076)
ERROR (CommandError): Unable to start the specified server(s).
```

Please find informations below to help:

```
nova list
+--------------------------------------+------------------+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+
| ID                                   | Name             | Status | Task State | Power State | Networks            |
+--------------------------------------+------------------+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+
| e7030ddb-df04-4d7e-b3ca-ac18b744d434 | admin_instance_1 | ACTIVE | -          | NOSTATE     | admin_net=10.10.0.5 |
+--------------------------------------+------------------+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

but when i run:

```
nova-manage network list

id      IPv4                    IPv6            start address   DNS1            DNS2            VlanID          project         uuid
Command failed, please check log for more info
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 CRITICAL nova [req-748ae5d9-1aee-4d97-8149-b845cf8456d2 - - - - -] OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/bin/nova-manage", line 10, in <module>
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     sys.exit(main())
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/cmd/manage.py", line 1443, in main
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     ret = fn(*fn_args, **fn_kwargs)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "<string>", line 2, in list
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/cmd/manage.py", line 504, in validate_network_plugin
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     return f(*args, **kwargs)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/cmd/manage.py", line 571, in list
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     networks = db.network_get_all(context.get_admin_context())
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/db/api.py", line 968, in network_get_all
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     return IMPL.network_get_all(context, project_only)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/db/sqlalchemy/api.py", line 216, in wrapper
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     return f(*args, **kwargs)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/db/sqlalchemy/api.py", line 2918, in network_get_all
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     project_only=project_only).all()
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/db/sqlalchemy/api.py", line 275, in model_query
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     session = get_session(use_slave=use_slave)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/db/sqlalchemy/api.py", line 182, in get_session
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     facade = _create_facade_lazily(_MAIN_FACADE, conf_group)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/db/sqlalchemy/api.py", line 164, in _create_facade_lazily
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     _ENGINE_FACADE[facade] = _create_facade(conf_group)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/db/sqlalchemy/api.py", line 156, in _create_facade
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     retry_interval=conf_group.retry_interval)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_db/sqlalchemy/enginefacade.py", line 943, in __init__
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     slave_connection=slave_connection)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_db/sqlalchemy/enginefacade.py", line 338, in _start
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     engine_args, maker_args)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_db/sqlalchemy/enginefacade.py", line 362, in _setup_for_connection
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     sql_connection=sql_connection, **engine_kwargs)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_db/sqlalchemy/engines.py", line 152, in create_engine
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     test_conn = _test_connection(engine, max_retries, retry_interval)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_db/sqlalchemy/engines.py", line 326, in _test_connection
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     return engine.connect()
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2018, in connect
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 72, in __init__
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     if connection is not None else engine.raw_connection()
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2104, in raw_connection
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     self.pool.unique_connection, _connection)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2078, in _wrap_pool_connect
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     e, dialect, self)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1401, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     util.raise_from_cause(newraise, exc_info)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 199, in raise_from_cause
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2074, in _wrap_pool_connect
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     return fn()
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 318, in unique_connection
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 713, in _checkout
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 480, in checkout
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     rec = pool._do_get()
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1151, in _do_get
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     return self._create_connection()
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 323, in _create_connection
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 449, in __init__
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     self.connection = self.__connect()
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 607, in __connect
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     connection = self.__pool._invoke_creator(self)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 97, in connect
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 385, in connect
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
2016-02-23 11:48:36.074 37886 ERROR nova
```

Thanks for your help